# Collection View Cell Returning Nil only in 1 case of Many

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a **collectionViewController** as a form for user submission with two sections:

1. Mandatory
2. Optional..

Each section has a custom class with relevant data in it based on user information with 4 items to choose from. On `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, the user highlights the cell that best meets their criteria. I have a button whose target is to upload the user selected cells into my cloud backend. The information is coming from the `collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()` as I have created an array of the cells' indexPaths that the user has selected and each section may only have one selected row. I have gone through every combination of submission and only when the user submits section 0 item 0 and section 1 item 3, it fails to register the proper cell for the first section's selection. When I breakpoint the relevant lines, I am able to get the cell information the user selected in this case, but otherwise it returns nil for my collectionview cell and will not allow me to pull the right cell tag.

```
//within my didSelectItemAtIndexPath
//I am properly adding and removing indexPaths..can add the code in if needed
selectItems = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()//indexPath array

//my button controlling the submission of data
bottomView.anchorButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postItems), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
//target method
```

I am trying to pass the cell tags into my database and they are unique per each section

```
func postItems() {

    let indexPath1 = selectItems

    var lTag: Int?
    var pTag: Int?


    if let indexPath = indexPath1 {

        //I have printed the selected indexPath to make sure I am passing the right values
        // when only the mandatory section is returned, there isnt a problem
        //returning the cell type that I want and the cell returns the value I want
        if indexPath.count == 1 {
            if indexPath[0].section == 0 {

                if  let customCell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[0])  {
                    let cell = customCell as! CustomCell1
                    lTag = cell.tag

                }

            } else if indexPath[0].section == 1 {
                if let customCell2 = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[0]) {
                    let cell2 = customCell2 as! CustomCell2
                    pTag = cell2.tag
                }
            }
        }

        //the problem occurs when I have my optional section included
        if indexPath.count == 2 {

            //the problem occurs here..can not unwrap the cell for this indexPath (0-0)
            //but will do so when in a breakpoint..does not have a problem for
            other combinations (e.g. 0-0 and 1-0/1-1/1-2)
            if indexPath[0].section == 0 {

                if let customCell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[0])  {
                    let cell = customCell as! CustomCell
                    lTag = cell.tag


                }

            } else if indexPath[0].section == 1 {
                if let customCell2 = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[0]) {
                    let cell2 = customCell2 as! CustomCell2
                    pTag = cell2.tag

                }
            }


            if indexPath[1].section == 0 {

                if  let customCell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[1])  {
                    let cell = customCell as! CustomCell
                    lTag = cell.tag

                }
            }  else if indexPath[1].section == 1 {
                if let customCell2 = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath[1]) {
                    let cell2 = customCell2 as! CustomCell2
                    pTag = cell2.tag


                }
            }
        }
    }

    if lTag != nil {
        print("Tag isn't nil")

    } else {

        print("Tag is nil because cell is nil value and could not be unwrapped")
    }
}
```

The end is just being used to test whether or not the Tag having issues has been assigned a value. I am not sure if there is a better way to check if multiple indexPaths are selected based on their sections, but until I discovered this bug I thought this code would do.

Is there a reason the cell would return nil for only `0-0` when `0-0` and `1-3` are selected. Occasionally the cell does unwrap and take the value of my custom cell, but most of the time it does not.

Comment: Is there any chance that for the case that you mentioned above, the cell at 0-0 is not visible on the screen? Maybe the user scrolled down, and the first item of your collection view moves up and can no longer be seen when making the submission?

Comment: yes it is not visible..does that mean I need to reload the collectionview to be able to access it? I was reading on on posts about collection views that sometimes you need to collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded() but not sure where that reload would occur..what do you suggest?

Comment: There's your problem. CollectionViews and TableViews only maintain cells that are visible, those that are not visible are reused. Hence we use the dequeCell function. I assume that you want to get some data from the cells, maybe some text values. I would suggest you to change your logic a bit. Instead of getting the data from the cells themselves, store the data in arrays. Then access the data using the indexPath as an index. Hope this makes sense. If you still need more help feel free to ask

Comment: this does in fact seem to be my problem..when part of the first section is visible on the screen: the cell unwraps, otherwise it does not

Comment: Yes because once it completely dissapears from the screen, the collectionview recycles it. You can no longer access it using the indexPath

Comment: Applied what you recommended and my issue is now resolved. Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: Glad to have been a help